# How do you calculate the square root of a Big Int in Go?

Tags: go

I'm attempting to calculate the square root of a Big Int in Go, but I'm not sure if I'm using the function correctly (or even the correct function).

Here is what I have so far:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)

func main() {
    x := big.NewInt(10)
    fmt.Print(x.ModSqrt(big.NewInt(2), big.NewInt(1)))
}
```

I am trying to calculate the square root of 10, but the output of this code is `<nil>`.

Can someone please explain how to use this method correctly as I don't understand the documentation and I can't find any usages of this elsewhere that might help me understand how to use the method?

Comment: ModSqrt has pretty much nothing to do with what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `big` package contains nothing for taking square roots. You'll have to implement it yourself. `ModSqrt`, in particular, is useless to you; it's a modular arithmetic thing.

Comment: Ah ok, I figured that was probably the wrong thing to be doing. I know a simpler solution than implementing Sqrt in this case, but I really hope they add that function in the future. Thank you for your reply!